# Combine two variables in lightning component

Tags: javascript-controller, code

How to combine two variable in same variable . I want to get both of values in another variables groupMembers3.

```
const groupMembers = component.get('v.usersToAdd').map(u => u.Id) ;
const groupMembers2 = component.get('v.groupsToAdd').map(u => u.Id) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be done with [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
const groupMembers3 = groupMembers.concat(groupMembers2);
```

Note that the original two variables are not modified; a new Array is returned.